# Hotspot's scavenge GC stops running, leaving only the mark-sweep GC

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm-hotspot

I'm experiencing something weird with Hotspot's GC in a certain program. Sometimes, it seems almost as if the scavenge GC just dies, leaving only the mark-sweep GC running instead every time the Eden space fills up. Needless to say, this is horrible for performance. I haven't managed to figure out the conditions for this issue to occur.

Looking at a JVM with this behavior right now, the old-gen is 170 MB (used and max) and never grows or shrinks over a collection, the Eden gen is 85 MB, the Survivor spaces are never used whatsoever (which I guess is consistent with the scavenge GC not running), and the total allocated heap size is 256 MB (matching, obviously, Old+Eden).

Any clues as to what might cause this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect that the heap is too full.  If the old space + eden space add up to the max heap space, then there is no room for a survivor space and a generational collector can't be run.

Try increasing the maximum heap space.

---

The point is that there has to be enough free space in the survivor space(s) to hold all objects that survive the collection of the eden space.  If the free space isn't available, then a copying collector cannot work and the JVM has to fall back to mark and sweep.

This is fundamental to how generational / copying collectors work.

Like I said, try increasing the heap space.

Comment: I forgot to mention it, but while the survivor spaces are empty, they are not zero in size. VisualGC says that S0 is 576 kB and S1 is 512 kB, which is more than I normally see in live VMs (a properly function one I'm looking at right now has survivor spaces that are 448 kB each).Given that, could that explanation still hold? It is true that both the Eden and Old-Gen spaces are as large as they are allocated, but should that prevent the Scavenge GC from running?

Comment: Agreed. I had simply never considered what the GC might do in memory-pressed situations and labored under the idea that the eden space is always discarded entirely after a GC, so I couldn't understand what was happening. I never even realized that I was becoming low on memory. Thanks!

Comment: You certainly do seem to be right, but that does make me wonder what really happens at that time. When the eden space fills up, and there isn't enough space in either the survivor or old-gen spaces, where do the still-live objects in the eden space go? Obviously, the JVM doesn't throw an OutOfMemoryException or anything. Is the eden space simply compacted?

Comment: *"Is the eden space simply compacted?"* - I think so.  What other alternative is there?  Anyway, the best idea is to avoid getting into that situation in the first place.